# Introsort in Python, can anybody point out my mistake?

Tags: python, algorithm, introsort

Trying to implement Introsort using Python.

The pseudo-code given is:

```
1 n ←|A| 
2 if n ≤ 1 
3 return 
4 elseif d = 0 
5 Heap-Sort(A) 
6 else 
7 p ← Partition(A) // Partitions A and returns pivot position 
8 Intro-Sort(A[0:p],d−1) 
9 Intro-Sort(A[p+1:n],d−1)
```

My source code is:

```
import math

def introSort(a,d):
    n = len(a)
    if n <= 1:
        return
    elif d == 0:
        heapSort(a)
    else:
        p = partition(a)
        a1 = a[0:p]
        a2 = a[p+1:n]
        introSort(a1, d-1)
        introSort(a2, d-1)
        a = a1 + [a[p]] + a2

def heapSort (a):
    END = len(a)
    for k in range (math.floor(END/2) - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(a, END, k)

    for k in range(END, 1, -1):
        swap(a, 0, k-1)
        heapify(a, k-1, 0)

def partition(a):
    x = a[len(a) - 1]
    i = -1
    for j in range(0, len(a) - 2):
        if a[j] <= x:
            i = i + 1
            swap(a, i, j)
    swap(a, i + 1, len(a) - 1)
    return i + 1

def swap(a, i, j):
    tmp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = tmp

def heapify(a,iEnd,iRoot):
    iL = 2*iRoot + 1
    iR = 2*iRoot + 2
    if iR < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL] and a[iRoot] >= a[iR]):
            return

        else:
            if(a[iL] > a[iR]):
                j = iL
            else: 
                j = iR
            swap(a, iRoot, j)
            heapify(a, iEnd, j)

    elif iL < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL]):
            return
        else:
            swap(a, iRoot, iL)
            heapify(a,iEnd,iL)

    else: 
        return

a = [3,5,6,1,23,521,6243,632,123,53,62,421,15,672,7,435,21]

introSort(a,2)

print(a)
```

The result given was wrong:

```
>python introsort.py
[3, 5, 6, 1, 15, 7, 21, 632, 123, 53, 62, 421, 23, 672, 521, 435, 6243]
```

It seems that it stopped straight after partition and the sorting on sublists was not working. It was clear that 21 was the pivot and the partition worked perfectly.

Can anybody point out my mistake? Thank you very much!

Comment: `a = a1 + [a[p]] + a2` isn't going to do anything to the input list. That's just rebinding a local variable.

Comment: How to fix this? I tried to use introSort(a[0:p],d-1) and so on, it didn't work

Comment: Your partition function is definitely wrong.  Try putting a print statement in the inner loop and running just the partition function to look closely at what it's doing.

Comment: put `print "before end a=",a` after `a = a1 + [a[p]] + a2` and set `1` in `introSort(b,2)` . You'll get `before end a= [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 15, 21, 23, 53, 62, 123, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 6243]

[3, 5, 6, 1, 15, 7, 21, 632, 123, 53, 62, 421, 23, 672, 521, 435, 6243]
`. It doesn't change final array

Comment: @Z.Yan: you can fix it by `a.insert(index, value)` and `a.pop(index+1)`

Comment: @Z.Yan: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much but it failed when using the list given above, it changed 435 to 6243. I actually got idea to fix this and solved the problem. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Z.Yan: Oh, yes. It fails now, I see. In addition, the code you give fails too with error on "math.floor(END/2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed this by using a helper function that calls heapsort on a piece of the list. Instead of doing it by modify the heapsort function, I did this in a separate copy and update the sorted elements back in the original list. The code shown as:

```
import math

def introSort(a, d, start, end):
    n = end - start
    if n <= 1:
        return
    elif d == 0:
        introHS(a, start, end)
    else:
        p = partition(a, start, end)
        introSort(a, d-1, start, p)
        introSort(a, d-1, p+1, end)

def introHS (a, start, end):
    b = a[start:end]
    heapSort(b)
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        a[start+i] = b[i]

def heapSort (a):
    END = len(a)
    for k in range (math.floor(END/2) - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(a, END, k)

    for k in range(END, 1, -1):
        swap(a, 0, k-1)
        heapify(a, k-1, 0)

def partition(a, start, end):
    x = a[end-1]
    i = start-1
    for j in range(start, end-1):
        if a[j] <= x:
            i=i+1
            swap(a, i, j)
    swap(a, i+1, end-1)
    return i+1

def swap(a, i, j):
    tmp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = tmp

def heapify(a,iEnd,iRoot):
    iL = 2*iRoot + 1
    iR = 2*iRoot + 2
    if iR < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL] and a[iRoot] >= a[iR]):
            return

        else:
            if(a[iL] > a[iR]):
                j = iL
            else: 
                j = iR
            swap(a, iRoot, j)
            heapify(a, iEnd, j)

    elif iL < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL]):
            return
        else:
            swap(a, iRoot, iL)
            heapify(a,iEnd,iL)

    else: 
        return
```

It worked fine by testing with:

```
a = [3,5,6,1,23,521,6243,632,123,53,62,421,15,672,7,435,21,123,41,52,6234,11,55,6345,324,58,46,2,123,152,6156,46,34,3426,5341,16,3314,34,73416,345]
print("Original:")
print(a)
for i in range(0,15):
    introSort(a,i,0,len(a))
    print("d=" + str(i))
    print(a)
```

Giving:

```
>Original:
>[3, 5, 6, 1, 23, 521, 6243, 632, 123, 53, 62, 421, 15, 672, 7, 435, 21, 123, 41, 52, 6234, 11, 55, 6345, 324, 58, 46, 2, 123, 152, 6156, 46, 34, 3426, 5341, 16, 3314, 34, 73416, 345]
>d=0
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=1
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=2
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=3
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=4
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=5
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=6
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=7
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=8
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=9
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=10
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=11
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=12
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=13
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
>d=14
>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 15, 16, 21, 23, 34, 34, 41, 46, 46, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 123, 123, 123, 152, 324, 345, 421, 435, 521, 632, 672, 3314, 3426, 5341, 6156, 6234, 6243, 6345, 73416]
```

Comment: Looks like it might be numba compatible

Comment: Darn - maybe not because of the recursion. Gives me "compiler re-entrant to the same function signature" error

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
a = a1 + [a[p]] + a2
```

And insert

```
for i in range(0, len(a1)):
    a.insert(i, a1[i])
    a.pop(i+1)
for i in range(0, len(a2)-1):
    a.insert(i+p+1, a2[i])
    a.pop(i+p+2)
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math


def introSort(a,d):
    n = len(a)
    if n <= 1:
        return
    elif d == 0:
        heapSort(a)
    else:
        p = partition(a)
        a1 = a[:p]
        a2 = a[p+1:n]
        introSort(a1, d-1)
        introSort(a2, d-1)
        for i in range(0, len(a1)):
            a.insert(i, a1[i])
            a.pop(i+1)
        for i in range(0, len(a2)-1):
            a.insert(i+p+1, a2[i])
            a.pop(i+p+2)

def heapSort (a):
    END = len(a)
    for k in range ( int(math.floor(END/2)) - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(a, END, k)

    for k in range(END, 1, -1):
        swap(a, 0, k-1)
        heapify(a, k-1, 0)

def partition(a):
    hi = len(a)-1
    x = a[hi]
    i = 0
    for j in range(0, hi-1):
        if a[j] <= x:
            swap(a, i, j)
            i = i + 1
    swap(a, i, hi)
    return i

def swap(a, i, j):
    tmp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[j]
    a[j] = tmp

def heapify(a,iEnd,iRoot):
    iL = 2*iRoot + 1
    iR = 2*iRoot + 2
    if iR < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL] and a[iRoot] >= a[iR]):
            return

        else:
            if(a[iL] > a[iR]):
                j = iL
            else: 
                j = iR
            swap(a, iRoot, j)
            heapify(a, iEnd, j)
    elif iL < iEnd:
        if (a[iRoot] >= a[iL]):
            return
        else:
            swap(a, iRoot, iL)
            heapify(a,iEnd,iL)

    else: 
        return

a = [3,5,6,1,23,521,6243,632,123,53,62,421,15,672,7,435,21]
print(a)

introSort(a,2)

print(a)
```

Also, see an answer about references in Python https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/9210255